# Pathauto module doesn't translate urls generated by l(), url() to aliases, should it?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

Pathauto **readme** says:

> If you use the "system path" (i.e.
>   node/10) for menu items and settings
>   like that, Drupal will replace it with
>   the url_alias.

But in my case links stay the same:

```
echo l('test', 'node/329'); // returns: node/329, should return: about-us
```

It is first time I'm using Pathauto, I was expecting it to work out-of-the-box as I followed all the instructions and there was nowhere mentioned any special url-translation activation procedure or something (is there one?).

When I paste domain.com/about-us into the browser address bar it manages to load proper page. But it doesn't translate my links.

Any idea what could be wrong or where I should I start to repair it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the reason. My admin area is dual-languaged and while I generate aliases in English, front-end runs in Dutch. Once I switched admin and front-end to the same language I got it working as expected.

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't understand what you  mean by "dual-languaged"?